# Secure ASP.NET WebAPI with O365

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, office365, azure-active-directory

I am trying to find a solution for this scenario:
We created a provider hosted sharepoint app which is basically a SPA Website.
Of course, as every SPA Website, there is a Web API. I'd like to protect this Web API and enforce an authentication with a valid O365 token.
How can i protect a Web API with O365? Is the only way to got directly through AAD?

Thank you for any hints.
Best
Laurin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office365 uses Azure AD behind the scenes so to secure your API you have to go through Azure Active Directory.

There a few steps to configuring the authentication:

1. [Register your application with ADD](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2015/04/30/register-your-application-in-azure-ad.aspx)
2. Get an access token for you user from ADD via [ADAL Javascript library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)
3. Call the api with the access token

There is a sample SPA using Azure Active directory located [here.](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet)

The code that handles the authentication in WebAPI is located in the `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` file.  Import the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory` name space and set up the pipepline to user Azure Active Directory authentication:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            });
    }

}
```

To lock down an API route be sure to put an `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller or action.

Comment: Thank you very much. So i take this as a confirmation that the only way to secure a web api is to use AAD, there is no other way to do so via O365 without registring the app in the aad.